# Thymeleaf Property or field 'datas' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm getting the error: Property or field 'datas' cannot be found on null on thymeleaf.

I've seen similar problems, but can't find the problem with my code.

Basically, i have a list of and object named Months with two attributes: Name(String) and Dates(List).

Here is the controller

```
@PostConstruct
   public void inicializar() {
         System.out.println("INICIALIZANDO...");             
         months = DrawCalendarTable.calendarTable(2016); // list of object 'months' with name and list of dates as string
         for(Months month : months){
             System.out.println(month.toString()); //just for test... print the data i want correctly
         }
   }

   @RequestMapping("/calendario")
   public ModelAndView listar(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("calendarTable");        
    mv.addObject("listOfMonths", months);
    return mv;
```

And here is the HTML

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                    style="vertical-align: center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th th:each="months : ${listOfMonths}" th:text="${months.name}">months</th> <!-- This works just fine. Also, if i use ${months.datas} it also works-->                                                          
                            <!-- Lista de Meses -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Lista Funcionarios -->
                            <td th:text="Anderson">Anderson</td>                                
                            <td >
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <tr th:each="days : ${months.datas}"> <!-- Here, months.data does not work. ERROR: CANNOT BE FOUND ON NULL-->
                                        <td th:text="F"></td>
                                        <!-- Desenha celulas de dia, de acordo com o mes -->
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have the proper get method for the field on the Object Months:

```
public List<String> getDatas() {
    return datas;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object you've added to your model is named "listOfMonths."  There is no object on your model named "months", so when it gets to this line:

```
<tr th:each="days : ${months.datas}">
```

months is null.  The top line works, because you've defined "months" before you use it.

```
th:each="months : ${listOfMonths}"
```

Comment: when i do 'months : ${listOfMonths}' don't i have this objetct as months.name and months.datas ?

The months.data in 'th:each="days : ${months.datas}' is not the same object as the prior?

Comment: The "months" in the <th> is only available to the <th> tag itself and tags that appear inside of <th></th>.  You have define the variable again later, if you want to use it again.